# Why do we need to use unless and "?" together instead of if alone

Tags: coffeescript

what is the need for using unless and "?" together when you can use if like in this case

```
unless person.present?
```

is equivalent to

```
if person.present
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're not equivalent.

`doSomeThing() unless person.present?`
will execute only if `person.present` is `null`

`doSomeThing() unless person.present`
will execute if `person.present` is a `false` value

`doSomeThing() if person.present`
will execute if `person.present` is a `true` value

check the [compiled javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert('person.present%20is%20null')%20unless%20person.present%3F%0A%0Aalert('person.present%20is%20a%20false%20value')%20unless%20preson.present%0A%0Aalert('person%20present')%20if%20person.present).

Comment: doSomeThing() unless person.present? will execute only if person.present is null **or undefined**

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that you're succumbing to the typo in your question. Unless you have a 'p *er* sent' attribute on `person`, it'll always be undefined, which is falsey.